# How do I center 2 divs in HTML Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, apache, twitter-bootstrap-3, center

As the title says, how do I center two divs next to each other perfectly?

My HTML: (or well, a bit of it)

```
<section class="team" id="team">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>The team behind CatCraft</h3>
        <div class="divider">
            <div class="hr">
                <div class="hr-dot"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row row-centered">
                <div class="team-centered col-md-4">
                    <img src="http://cravatar.eu/helmhead/6a940db5e02d4bf79db9203a8b126f0d/140.png" alt="catx">
                    <h4 class="bold">CatX (Owner)</h4>
                    <p>Hi! I'm CatX and I'm the owner of CatCraft. I like anime and tech stuff. My favourite server is bending. =^_^=</p>
                </div>
                <div class="team-centered col-md-4">
                    <img src="http://cravatar.eu/helmhead/ef4fbdb6d629480d8f98ed9919c111e9/140.png" alt="__ast__">
                    <h4 class="bold">__Ast__ (Co-Owner)</h4>
                    <p>Example text, pls write something ;-;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

My CSS: (same here, this isn't all)

> I tried to make a box for the css above too but it didn't work. http://pastebin.com/SzhAmh3f

Basically the problem I'm having is that the code above works kind of but one of the blocks are a little bit lower than the other and i have no idea why.
Yes, I know that there are other posts about this subject but no one worked for me so I decided to open my own.

Comment: Can you paste a bootply or jsfiddle link for me? PasteBin is blocked by my company...

Comment: can you also post your CSS so we can see what your other class/id properties are?

Comment: are you ok with flexbox solution ? - its super simple FYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of unwanted styles actually to achieve this, you simply need the below code on your `team-centered` class. Remove `row-centered` class. It should look like this

**CSS**

```
.team img {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px auto 40px;
}
.team-centered {
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="team" id="team">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>The team behind CatCraft</h3>
        <div class="divider">
            <div class="hr">
                <div class="hr-dot"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="team-centered">
                    <img src="http://cravatar.eu/helmhead/6a940db5e02d4bf79db9203a8b126f0d/140.png" alt="catx">
                    <h4 class="bold">CatX (Owner)</h4>
                    <p>Hi! I'm CatX and I'm the owner of CatCraft. I like anime and tech stuff. My favourite server is bending. =^_^=</p>
                </div>
                <div class="team-centered">
                    <img src="http://cravatar.eu/helmhead/ef4fbdb6d629480d8f98ed9919c111e9/140.png" alt="__ast__">
                    <h4 class="bold">__Ast__ (Co-Owner)</h4>
                    <p>Example text, pls write something ;-;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now they are at the same height! How do I make the "<p>" text not spread out so much, how do I make it more compact?

Comment: yes then you will have to give these styles for the `<p>` tags - `p { width: 50%; margin: auto; }`. I still suggest using flexbox though. Avoids all these extra changes. :-) Hope you got your answer